# flutter ternary with int - error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter

I use the ternary operator to compare the number of comments and display different widgets depending on the result of the condition

```
                    (feedElement.cntComments > 0)
                    ? Text(
                        feedElement.cntComments.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(
                        'Comments',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
```

but I get an error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result'

model feed this

```
class FeedModel {
  String avatar;
  String account;
  String accountName;
  String message;
  bool verified;
  String timeAgo;
  int cntComments;
  int cntLikes;
  int cntShares;

  FeedModel({
    required this.avatar,
    required this.account,
    required this.accountName,
    required this.message,
    required this.verified,
    required this.timeAgo,
    required this.cntComments,
    required this.cntLikes,
    required this.cntShares,
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show more complete code?

Comment: Can you share how are you creating the `feedElement` object? Since the `cntComments` field is non-nullable, and you set it as required in the constructor, this is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, restarting the SDK helped :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).